# LoadJDBCDriver error Netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans

I'm completing a java Intermediate level project and i've come across a run time error when running my test classes. I've provided code of my DB_SETUP,DB_MANAGER  and my TEST_INSTRUMENT class. The error is in relation to the JDBC Connection. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you !

DB_MANAGER

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DB_MANAGER {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DB_MANAGER.class.getName());

void loadJDBCDriver() {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

void checkConnection() {

    loadJDBCDriver();

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    String strUrl = "jdbc:derby:billsdb;create=true";
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle.getStackTrace());
    }

}

Connection getConnection() {

    loadJDBCDriver();

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    String strUrl = "jdbc:derby:billsdb;create=true";
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle.getStackTrace());
    }

    return dbConnection;

}
}
```

DB_SETUP

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

  public class DB_SETUP {

 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DB_MANAGER.class.getName());

void createTables() {

    DB_MANAGER dmbgr = new DB_MANAGER();

    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();

    executeSqlScript(con, new File("sql\\createdb.txt"));
}

void insertSetupData() {

    DB_MANAGER dmbgr = new DB_MANAGER();

    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();

    executeSqlScript(con, new File("sql\\insertdata.txt"));
}

public void showData() {

    Statement stmt;

    DB_MANAGER dmbgr = new DB_MANAGER();

    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();

    /** Prints all data from the USERDETAILS Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from USERDETAILS");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            String userName = results.getString(2);
            String fName = results.getString(3);
            String lName = results.getString(4);
            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + userName + "\t\t" + fName + "\t\t" + lName);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the INSTRUMENTS Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from INSTRUMENTS");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            String type = results.getString(2);
            String name = results.getString(3);
            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + type + "\t\t" + name );
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the VOTE Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from VOTE");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            String opendate = results.getString(2);
            String closedate = results.getString(3);
            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + opendate + "\t\t" + closedate);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the VOTEINST Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from VOTEINST");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            int voteid = results.getInt(2);
            int instrid = results.getInt(3);
            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + voteid + "\t\t" + instrid);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the BANKDETAILS Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from BANKDETAILS");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int accnum = results.getInt(1);
            String name = results.getString(2);
            int branch = results.getInt(3);
            String collect = results.getString(4);
            int userid = results.getInt(5);
            logger.info(accnum + "\t\t" + name + "\t\t" + branch + "\t\t" + collect + "\t\t" + userid);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the USERVOTE Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from USERVOTE");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            int userid = results.getInt(2);
            int voteinstid = results.getInt(3);
            float percent = results.getFloat(4);
            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + userid + "\t\t" + voteinstid + "\t\t" + percent );
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the VOTERESULT Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from VOTERESULT");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            int voteinstid = results.getInt(2);
            float avgpercent = results.getFloat(3);

            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + voteinstid + "\t\t" + voteinstid + "\t\t" + avgpercent);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the MKTHISTORY Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from MKTHISTORY");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            float price = results.getFloat(2);
            String update = results.getString(3);
            int instrid = results.getInt(4);

            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + price + "\t\t" + update + "\t\t" + instrid);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    /** Prints all data from the CORPEVENTS Table **/
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from CORPEVENTS");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            String type = results.getString(2);
            String date = results.getString(3);
            String desc = results.getString(4);
            int instrid = results.getInt(5);

            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + type + "\t\t" + date + "\t\t" + desc + "\t\t" + instrid);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select * from DIVIDEND");

        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------");

        while (results.next()) {
            int id = results.getInt(1);
            double payment = results.getDouble(2);
            String date = results.getString(3);
            int instrid = results.getInt(4);

            logger.info(id + "\t\t" + payment + "\t\t" + date + "\t\t" + instrid);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null,sqlExcept);
    }

}

public void executeSqlScript(Connection conn, File inputFile) {

    // Delimiter
    String delimiter = ";";

    // Create scanner
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(delimiter);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e1);
        return;
    }

    // Loop through the SQL file statements
    Statement currentStatement = null;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        // Get statement
        String rawStatement = scanner.next();
        try {
            // Execute statement
            currentStatement = conn.createStatement();
            currentStatement.execute(rawStatement);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            // Release resources
            if (currentStatement != null) {
                try {
                    currentStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);;
                }
            }
            currentStatement = null;
        }
    }
}
 }
```

TEST_INSTRUMENT

```
public class TEST_INSTRUMENT {

public static void main(String[] args){

 DB_MANAGER mngr = new DB_MANAGER();
   mngr.checkConnection();

   DB_SETUP sdb = new DB_SETUP();
   sdb.createTables();
   sdb.insertSetupData();



   DAO_INSTRUMENT iDAO = new DAO_INSTRUMENT();
   iDAO.getAllInstruments();
   /** This displays the newly edited tables, after each DAO is tested **/


   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("All Instruments.");
   for(CLS_INSTRUMENT instru: iDAO.getAllInstruments()){
        System.out.println(instru.getName());}

   iDAO.insertInstru(new CLS_INSTRUMENT("BOND", "DAC BOND", "Blah", "Blah blah blah", "17.11.2014", 9, "sdsdas", 2, null, null, 0, 0.85));

   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Instrument Added.");
   for(CLS_INSTRUMENT instru: iDAO.getAllInstruments()){
        System.out.println(instru.getName());}

   iDAO.updateInstrument(new CLS_INSTRUMENT(1, "SHARE", "ABC LTD"));
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Instrument Editted.");
   for(CLS_INSTRUMENT instru: iDAO.getAllInstruments()){
        System.out.println(instru.getName());}

   iDAO.deleteInstrument(new CLS_INSTRUMENT(1, "SHARE", "ABC LTD"));
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Instrument Deleted.");
   for(CLS_INSTRUMENT instru: iDAO.getAllInstruments()){
        System.out.println(instru.getName());
   }
   }
  }
```

Error Stacktrace

```
   run:
   Nov 22, 2016 2:19:39 PM is3312project.DB_MANAGER loadJDBCDriver
   SEVERE: null
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:        org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
   at is3312project.DB_MANAGER.loadJDBCDriver(DB_MANAGER.java:26)
   at is3312project.DB_MANAGER.checkConnection(DB_MANAGER.java:34)
   at is3312project.TEST_INSTRUMENT.main(TEST_INSTRUMENT.java:18)
```

Comment: Post the error stacktrace.

Comment: I've Updated it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `derby.jar` to CLASSPATH to resolve this `ClassNotFoundException` based on the version of Derby that you are using.

A quick look at [this](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/cdevdvlp40653.html) explains you that the JDBC driver comes along with the Derby database that you've used to connect to.

You've not mentioned any details on the version of Derby Database that you're using for your project, based on that would be your JDBC driver.

A quick look at the available Derby Downloads -  Page [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html)!